# How to find the Javascript that is not contained in a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a really, really nasty bit of JS code that I've inherited. The code is quite long, and quite obtrusive.  The functions defined are all about a thousand or so lines each...

Anyway, since there isn't a call to anything as elegant as onload, I am trying to figure out how what is on the screen gets on the screen.  Thus I need a way to separate the fly crap from the pepper as it were...

I need to be able to find the code that is not contained in functions and is just called "out in the wild" so I can find out where this silly program begins...does anybody know a good way to do this?

Comment: The functions are each a thousand lines? Every day that I come to StackOverflow, someone manages to say something that stuns me.

Comment: @Nosredna Don't look at me, I didn't write it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brute-force method could be to include some script at the very top (of the script includes) to set the document object to undefined/null so that any references to its methods will cause a runtime error. That may help you spot the line # and filename of the first bit of code that tries to get something on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox & Firebug -- set breakpoints and step through the code as it executes.  The other thing you could do is start refactoring into classes/objects and see what breaks in the console (due to no references).  I'd probably take a run through the debugger first, though.

Comment: I'd say the code is too messy for that...it wasn't exactly written by a JS guy...

Comment: ...it was written by a systems programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I might try using a regular expression to dump what's floating. That could get complicated, though, depending on the internal structure. Other than that, I can only think of trying firebug to step through the code. Either way, with giant monolithic files, you're in for a lot of work.

Comment: I like this idea...but I don't know where to find a regular expression for selecting functions (basically I'd need to invert that)

Answer (score 0):

You should try a debugger, look at [50 Useful JavaScript Tools](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/08/50-extremely-useful-javascript-tools/)